# Difference between using #include<filename> and #include<filename.h> in C++

Tags: c++, include, namespaces

What is the difference between using `#include<filename> and #include<filename.h`> in [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B)? Which of the two is used and why is it is used?

Comment: Voting to reopen. This question is about `<foo>` vs. `<foo.h>`, whereas [the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) is about `<foo(.h)>` vs `"foo(.h)"`. The linked question is certainly related and a useful resource, but it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

C++ only include-files not found in the C standard never used `filename.h` . Since the very first C++ Standard came out (1998) they have used `filename` for their own headers.

Files inherited by the C Standard became `cfilename` instead of `filename.h`. The C files inherited used like `filename.h` are deprecated, but still part of the C++ standard.

The difference is that names not defined as macros in C are found within namespace `std::` in `cfilename` in C++, while names in `filename.h` are within the global namespace scope. So you will find `::size_t` in stddef.h, and `std::size_t` in cstddef. Both are Standard C++, but use of ::size_t is deprecated (See Annex D of the C++ Standard).

Now those were the difference.

#### Why would you use `filename.h` ?

- Compatibility with C compilers
- Compatibility with very old C++ compilers

#### Why should you use `cfilename` ?

- Names are within namespace `std::` . No name-clashes anymore.
- New C++ features (e.g. overloaded math functions for float, long)
- C Compatibility Headers (`filename.h`) could disappear in future.

Comment: Thanks can you explian-The difference is that names not defined as macros in C are found within namespace std:: in cfilename in C++

Comment: Well. The preprocessor doesn't know about C++ namespaces. It doesn't care about any scope. So C++ cannot put macros into namespaces. The Standard explicitly says that even if C would allow implementing as functions,C++ implementations should still make them macros.That's consequent,and a good thing.

Comment: Even if they're deprecated, no sane compiler vender will ever deprecate the usage of `filename.h` in C++.  They'd break far too many programs and angry far too many customers/developers.

Comment: deprecating doesn't mean it won't work. you also woudn't notice anyway if there is no warning. after all, compilers aren't required to give any for them.

Comment: Deprecation is defined as " Normative for the current edition of the
Standard, but not guaranteed to be part of the Standard in future revisions."

Comment: Is your explanation still valid for `#include "foo.h"` and `#include "foo"`? Sorry, I am   a newbie.

Answer (score 22):

The `#include <foo.h>` was common in C++ code prior to the C++ standard. The standard changed it to `#include <foo>` with everything from the header placed in the `std` namespace. (Thanks to litb for pointing out that the standard has never allowed .h headers.)

There is no magic going on, the first looks for a file called 'foo.h' and the second for a file called 'foo'. They are two different files in the file system. The standard just changed the name of the file that should be included.

In most compilers the old headers are still there for backwards compatibility (and compatibility with C), but modern C++ programs that want to follow the standard should not use them.

In the case of standard C headers, the C++ versions have a c at the beginning, so the C header

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

becomes

```
#include <cstdio>
```

Comment: How? How did you simply write include in your answer? I'm totally baffled by your awesomeness :)

Comment: Code blocks written in backticks seems to do the right thing for lt and gt. =)

Comment: is it applicable to standard headers alone?

Comment: Yes. I'll add a line about that.

Comment: also, here you do the same mistake. filename.h (like iostream.h) was never part of any c+ standard.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that. I'll change it to read pre-standard.

Comment: Actually, #include <standard hdr> doesn't have to look for a file. It may be implemented otherwise, e.g. using precompiled headers. That can be faster (think shipping precompiled headers)

Comment: MSalters is right. it could be anything, including a virtual file within the compiler :)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But it works just as if it looked for a file, so I didn't feel it was relevant enough to mention.

Answer (score 7):

The old standard used the `#include <filename.h>` syntax. When namespaces and templates were added to the language, the standard was changed to `#include <filename>`.

This was done so that the standard library stuff could all be placed in the std namespace. Older code, which had no concept of namespaces would still work since the `#include <filename.h>` files don't use namespaces.

New code should **always** use the `#include <filename>` format. If you use the older format, all the symbols they define will be placed in the global namespace rather than std.

Comment: There was no "old standard" that used filename.h . That was merely common among compilers before the first c++ standard came out

Comment: :-) this is wat i like abt stackoverflow

Comment: ok, standard may have been a little strong. I should have said "de facto standard" or "common practice".

Answer (score 2):

Those without the .h is C++ header files while those with .h are C header files. This only applies to the standard header files in C++.

If you are including your own files or files that is not part of standard C++ you need to always write the complete file name (which can be anything).

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the standard libraries (because otherwise it wont work at all), the difference is

```
#include< header >
//my code
```

is the correct way to call the header according the the C++ standard, while

```
#include< header.h >
//my code
```

is deprecated (in the C++ standard, but still necessary according to the C99 standard) and came along with the rest of the C baggage.

So you should use:

```
#include< cmath >
//my code
```

not:

```
#include< math.h >
//my code
```

Comment: Its not deprecated, you have to use the .h files if you want to do C programming.