# How to include a file from another folder?

Tags: c++, include

In my current project I have separated my class files and my header files. My project structure currently looks like this:

- Project
- - Source

    - src

      - class1.cpp
      - class2.cpp
    - main.cpp
- - Header

    - include

      - class1.h
      - class2.h

My problem is that I do not know how to include the header files into the class files. Am I unable to link to headers that are not at the same level or in a child folder? Or is there some way to go from the project root and work my way down? For instance:
`#include "Project/Headers/include/class1.h"` inside the class1.cpp file

Comment: Probably you meant `#include` instead of `include`. Corrected for this.

Answer (score 29):

Assuming you want class1.cpp to include class1.h you would do something like this

```
#include "../../Header/class1.h"
```

The `..` tells the  tells the OS to jump 1 directory up when the compiler asks for the file.

Comment: The .. doesn't tell the compiler nothing. It tells the OS to jump 1 directory up when the compiler asks for the file.

Comment: It's a bad practice to use ".." and "." when including header files.

Comment: @mmohaveri can you explain why?

Comment: @JohnMcFarlane first of all, it's not portable and it's not in the standard, so for example your code won't work in Windows.
Second, It makes your code fragile, in the sense that a small change in your file locations can cause a build break.
Finally, it sometimes cause your code to work magically (for more information check 'bk1e' answer on the following post) which in turn makes your code even more fragile.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597318/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-relative-path-such-as-include-header-h-for-a-hea

Comment: Re. portability: provided the file is not missing, `#include "../foo.h"` works for VC++ the same as for GCC and Clang.

Comment: @mmohaveri Re. the standard: are you saying the standard in some way prohibits use of `..` for parent directories?

Comment: @mmohaveri Re. code working magically: if you have a bug in your code and some feature causes there to be no diagnostic, that is not an argument against ever using the feature. I suspect that @bk1e's example is actually quite rare and overlooks the disadvantages of relying on absolute paths combines with `-I` directives to look up physically local files. Thanks

Comment: @mmohaveri I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52144130/671509) to that question.

Answer (score 18):

You need to indicate the include path `<the directory containing Project>` to your compiler so that the compiler is able to find the included headers. Using gcc, you could use `-I` option, and using visual studio, you could use `/I`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem where my compiler could not find the header with a code::blocks C++ project (same file structure as OP) .

This worked for me:

```
#include "../include/class1.h"
```