# Eclipse CDT Consistently Producing Three Inclusion Related Errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, executable, binaryfiles, inclusion

Every time I make a new project in Eclipse Oxygen CDT, I'm always plagued by three main errors: "Type 'std::string' could not be resolved" (or similar inclusion problems), "Launch failed. Binaries not found," and "Launch failed.  Program file does not exist".

I feel like I have tried just about everything. I have researched and followed these questions: [Eclipse C++: Symbol 'std' could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814536/eclipse-c-symbol-std-could-not-be-resolved)
, [The program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690644/the-program-file-specified-in-the-launch-configuration-does-not-exist), [Launch Failed Binary not found Eclipse for C in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407430/launch-failed-binary-not-found-eclipse-for-c-in-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1)
, [Eclipse CDT project built but “Launch Failed. Binary Not Found”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023235/eclipse-cdt-project-built-but-launch-failed-binary-not-found)
, [“string could not resolved” error in Eclipse for C++ (Eclipse can't resolve standard library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905025/string-could-not-resolved-error-in-eclipse-for-c-eclipse-cant-resolve-stan)
, [C++ - Unresolved inclusion: iostream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373788/c-unresolved-inclusion-iostream)
, [Eclipse c++ Type could not be resolved error even though build is successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041453/eclipse-c-type-could-not-be-resolved-error-even-though-build-is-successful)
, and [How to include a file from another folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884983/how-to-include-a-file-from-another-folder)
.

Hi World Example:

```
/*
 * Hi_world.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 22, 2018
 *      Author: Me
 */

//I tried using the actual file paths but that didn't help either
#include <C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream>
#include <C:\MinGW\include\string.h>

using namespace std;//"Symbol 'std' could not be resolved" 

int main()
{
    std::string me = "hi world";//"Type 'std::string' could not be resolved"

    std::cout << me << std::endl;//"Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved"
                                 // and "Symbol 'endl' could not be resolved"
}
```

Note: I tried to get this to run for several hours one day, was unsuccessful, so I saved and exited eclipse and my computer. The next day I turned on my computer, cleaned, built, and ran my this program as is, and it ran corectly on first try (although the red squiggly lines didn't disappear).

Hear is this Programs build log:

```
12:37:15 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Hi world ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o Hi_world.o "..\\Hi_world.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\\MinGW" -o "Hi world.exe" Hi_world.o 

12:37:17 Build Finished (took 1s.47ms)
```

Hear is another example that still doesn't Run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "string.h"

int main ()
{
  time_t timer;
  struct tm y2k = {0};
  double seconds;

  y2k.tm_hour = 0;   y2k.tm_min = 0; y2k.tm_sec = 0;
  y2k.tm_year = 100; y2k.tm_mon = 0; y2k.tm_mday = 1;

  time(&timer);  /* get current time; same as: timer = time(NULL)  */

  seconds = difftime(timer,mktime(&y2k));

  printf ("%.f seconds since January 1, 2000 in the current timezone", seconds);

  return 0;
}
```

Note: This had all the inclusion errors mentioned before, but randomly between a clean and rebuild those red squiggly errors went away. However it still doesn't build and run correctly with the error message "Launch failed. Binary not found."

Hear is this programs build log:

```
12:40:10 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Time ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\5.3.0\\include\\c++\\debug" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o Time.o "..\\Time.cpp" 
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h: In member function 'std::__cxx11::string std::__cxx11::numpunct<_CharT>::grouping() const':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:1777:7: error: return type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' is incomplete
       { return this->do_grouping(); }
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h: In member function 'virtual std::__cxx11::string std::__cxx11::numpunct<_CharT>::do_grouping() const':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:1845:7: error: return type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' is incomplete
       { return _M_data->_M_grouping; }
       ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc: In member function 'void std::__numpunct_cache<_CharT>::_M_cache(const std::locale&)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:88:26: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'const string {aka const class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
    _M_grouping_size = __g.size();
                          ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:90:7: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'const string {aka const class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
    __g.copy(__grouping, _M_grouping_size);
       ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc: In member function '_InIter std::num_get<_CharT, _InIter>::_M_extract_float(_InIter, _InIter, std::ios_base&, std::ios_base::iostate&, std::__cxx11::string&) const':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:211:18: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
  __found_grouping.reserve(32);
                  ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:282:10: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
    __xtrc.clear();
          ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:296:27: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
       if (__found_grouping.size())
                           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:319:27: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
       if (__found_grouping.size() && !__found_dec)
                           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:355:27: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
       if (__found_grouping.size())
                           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc: In member function '_InIter std::num_get<_CharT, _InIter>::_M_extract_int(_InIter, _InIter, std::ios_base&, std::ios_base::iostate&, _ValueT&) const':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:468:20: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
    __found_grouping.reserve(32);
                    ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:554:22: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
  if (__found_grouping.size())
                      ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:567:55: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
  if ((!__sep_pos && !__found_zero && !__found_grouping.size())
                                                       ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc: In member function 'virtual _InIter std::num_get<_CharT, _InIter>::do_get(std::num_get<_CharT, _InIter>::iter_type, std::num_get<_CharT, _InIter>::iter_type, std::ios_base&, std::ios_base::iostate&, float&) const':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:695:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
       __xtrc.reserve(32);
             ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:697:33: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
       std::__convert_to_v(__xtrc.c_str(), __v, __err, _S_get_c_locale());
                                 ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc: In member function 'virtual _InIter std::num_get<_CharT, _InIter>::do_get(std::num_get<_CharT, _InIter>::iter_type, std::num_get<_CharT, _InIter>::iter_type, std::ios_base&, std::ios_base::iostate&, double&) const':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:710:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
       __xtrc.reserve(32);
             ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:712:33: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
       std::__convert_to_v(__xtrc.c_str(), __v, __err, _S_get_c_locale());
                                 ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc: In member function 'virtual _InIter std::num_get<_CharT, _InIter>::do_get(std::num_get<_CharT, _InIter>::iter_type, std::num_get<_CharT, _InIter>::iter_type, std::ios_base&, std::ios_base::iostate&, long double&) const':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:742:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
       __xtrc.reserve(32);
             ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:2651:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.tcc:744:33: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
       std::__convert_to_v(__xtrc.c_str(), __v, __err, _S_get_c_locale());
                                 ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\Time.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\stringfwd.h:71:11: note: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
     class basic_string;
           ^

12:40:10 Build Finished (took 656ms)
```

I am using a native install of Windows 10, and am using MinGW installed on my computer. What is strange about this problem is that I will start a new project, the inclusion errors will pop up, making it not be able to build or run, and thus causing the other two errors, I will then battle it for days, following the answers above and get no where. Then out of the blue, I will click "build and run" and the program will build correctly and run properly (so long as I don't changing the code or click "Clean" thereafter). It gets even worse if I try to make a class and include the classes header file, with all the method declarations, in the classes .cpp file with similar errors in the .cpp file as in the example above.

Could this be caused by a faulty insulation of Eclipse CDT, or of MinGW? Are there settings that I could change in Eclipse to designate where to look for its libraries (would that even help?)? Any help is GREATLY appreciated =).

Thanks!

Comment: Note: This is my first question on Stack Overflow. I would love feedback on how to make my question better in the comments. Thanks Guys!

Comment: You should post actual build log. "could not be resolved" may be Eclipse syntax highlighter complaints. And there is never need to use something like `<C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream>`.

Comment: Will do! Thanks!