# NDK - C Header File Symbolic Link - Does not compile

Tags: android, c, include, android-ndk

I am a total new-bee in NDK-C-Linux(Ubuntu) hive. And i'm totally lost.

I'm given an old project, which i'am having trouble even compiling.

### This does not compile:

```
source.c 
--header.h (../includes/header.h)(symbolic link to the real header file)
```

it recognizes the header.h file, ***but its only a link to the real header file***. so it complains.

### This compiles:

```
source.c 
--header.h
```

but if replace the link file with the real 'header.h' it works.

---

### The problem:

there are lots of header files. which i don't want to find and replace manually.
how can i make the compiler to look for the header file using the symbolic link file.

searching for link header, symbolic link does not yield useful result.

if i was able to get anything related, then this is it. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597318)

Comment: Why not add the path of the header file to the compiler include-path? And are you sure you meant 'inclues' or should that be 'includes' ?

Comment: well that was a typo in the post. for now i used 'Meld Diff Viewer', the problem is i will receive a new version again (no config mgmt, where i work). i'm using ndk-build, where should i set include-path. Android.mk seems to have the path set to it, the problem is it compiles for real files and not for links to the real header file.