# What does -I imply here in g++ command?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I understand that when compiling with g++, `-I` is used to include header files, and `-L` is used to link with library files. But here is a g++ compile command from [google-breakpad minidump_file_writer_unittest](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/source/browse/trunk/src/client/minidump_file_writer_unittest.cc) located at line `33`:

```
g++ -I../ ../common/convert_UTF.c \
 ../common/string_conversion.cc \
 minidump_file_writer.cc \
 minidump_file_writer_unittest.cc \
 -o minidump_file_writer_unittest
```

Now what exactly does `-I../` imply here? Is it including all the header files inside this directory and subdirectories?

Comment: It means add the parent directory to the include search path.

Comment: Google "man gcc": http://www.manpages.info/linux/gcc.1.html

Comment: @P0W yeah, pretty damning. :|

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-I` option specifies an extra directory where the compiler should look for headers, and `-I../` specifies that the extra directory is the parent directory of where the `g++` command is running.  Two of the source files are also found in (a sub-directory of) the parent directory.  The `/` is optional; the compilation would work fine with `-I ..` instead (the space between the flag and value is also optional).

Note that the `-I` option says nothing (directly) about which header files are included; it just says where to look for the headers.  The source code `#include` lines dictate which headers are included.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Quick question: so it will look now in all the sub-directories under this parent directory including the parent directory for header files? Am I correct?

Comment: Not really. When the preprocessor sees `#include "header1.h"`, it will look for a file `../header1.h` before going on to look in other standard locations. If it sees `#include "subdir/header2.h"`, it will look for a file `../subdir/header2.h` before going on to look in other standard locatins. If perchance it sees [`#include "../other/header3.h"`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/597318/), it will look for a file `../../other/header3.h` before looking in other places. Generally, with the `"header.h"` notation, it will look in the current directory first; for the `<header.h>` notation, it won't.