# How to specify #include<path> for Boost?

Tags: c++, boost

I specify a path like "#include "$Home/boost../../abcd.hpp" and the compiler does not recognize the path.

How do I set the path of boost in my include when the home directory is the path.

Comment: You need to pass include paths to the compiler (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738979/c-include-with-full-path)).

Comment: Which os and which compiler are you using?

Comment: `$Home` is interpolated in your shell. You can't use it in your source code.