# Include gsl_type.h. File not found

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors, makefile

It seems to be a common issue but I can't wrap solve this problem.

I have some .c code that I compile using a makefile. The goal is to create a shared object (.so) so that I can run the C code from R.

Here is my makefile:

```
obs = R_wrapper.o G.o develop.o utilities.o
CFLAGS = -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O3  -c
LFLAGS = -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -O3 -lgsl -lm -lgslcblas

R_wrapper : $(obs)
    $gcc $(LFLAGS) $(obs) -o R_wrapper.so

R_wrapper.o : R_wrapper.c constants.h develop.h G.h
    $gcc $(CFLAGS) R_wrapper.c

G.o : G.c G.h constants.h utilities.h develop.h 
    $gcc $(CFLAGS) G.c develop.c

develop.o : develop.c develop.h G.h constants.h
    $gcc $(CFLAGS) develop.c

utilities.o : utilities.c develop.h
    $gcc $(CFLAGS) utilities.c
```

It works fine on the computer in my lab but it doesn't work on my personal computer. What causes this issue is these two lines at the beginning of my R_wrapper.c.

```
#include </opt/local/include/gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include </opt/local/include/gsl/gsl_rng.h>
```

I have tried to move these files around and give different paths, put the files in the gal_type.h files in the same directory as my R_wrapper file, I have tried to rename my directories so that the path is more conventional but the OS did not give me the right to rename `opt` into `usr` (which probably makes obvious sense). I haven't created the makefile and don't fully get it. I would suppose I'd need to modify the path after the `-I` argument somewhere in `CFLAGS` OR `LFLAGS`.

**EDIT 1**

I changed `R_wrapper.c` on my lab computer to get rid of the whole path in `#include <...>`. Compilation failed as @Beta predicted. Then, I changed my makefile to add `-I/opt/local/include/gsl` to `CFLAGS`. I don't know what you mean by `Verify that the makefile still works.` I tried to compile with my edited makefile on my lab computer and it failed. I then re-edited my makefile changing `-I/opt/local/include/gsl` to `-I/usr/local/include/gsl` because on my lab computer the `gsl` folder is at `/usr/local/include/gsl`. `-I/opt/local/include/gsl` is the location of the `gsl` folder on my computer. So I am stuck here in your procedure.

**Edit 2**

I moved my `gsl` folder around my computer trying to include from different paths. And some interesting stuff happen. For example when I put my `gsl` folder in `Users/remi/Documents/Biologie/programing/C/` and write (in `CFLAGS`)

```
-I/Users/remi/Documents/Biologie/programing/C/
```

I get this error:

```
R_wrapper.c:43:10: fatal error: 'gsl_randist.h' file not found
#include <gsl_randist.h> // goal.
```

When I write (in `CFLAGS`)

```
Users/remi/Documents/Biologie/programing/C/gsl
```

I get this error message:

```
"In file included from R_wrapper.c:43: /Users/remi/Documents/Biologie/programing/C/gsl/gsl_randist.h:22:10: fatal error: 
      'gsl/gsl_rng.h' file not found
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>"
```

Comment: Judging from the message about `gsl/gsl_rng.h` not being found in Edit 2, you should be writing `#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>` (with the path prefix of `gsl/` before the header name) in your source code. This is a common convention. You then specify in the `-I` option the name of the directory containing the `gsl` subdirectory that contains the `gsl_*.h` headers. You should read the documentation, and if it says `#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>` or `#include "gsl/gsl_randist.h"`, that is what you should write in your code, because (as you've discovered the hard way) if you don't, it won't work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh! That solved my problem! Phew. I struggled a lot with this issue... that was actually simple (as usual). Thank you very much! Can you make an answer out of your comment so that I can check it?

Comment: Include the library using:

    #include <gsl/gsl>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comment to answer*</sup>

Judging from the message about `gsl/gsl_rng.h` not being found that is mentioned in Edit 2, you should be writing

```
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
```

(with the path prefix of `gsl/` before the header name) in your source code. This is a common convention. You then specify in the `-I` option the name of the directory containing the `gsl` subdirectory that contains the `gsl_*.h` headers.  In your Edit 2, you say you put the `gsl` directory into `/Users/remi/Documents/Biologie/programing/C/`, so you are then correct to use:

```
-I/Users/remi/Documents/Biologie/programing/C/
```

on the command line as you tried.

You should read the documentation, and if it says write either of these:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include "gsl/gsl_randist.h"
```

then that is what you should write in your code, because (as you've discovered the hard way) if you don't, it won't work.

[Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128940/beta)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27286838/15168) also states

> In general it's a bad idea to write paths into the `#include` statements unless you really have to; it causes just this kind of problem.

I agree, but would state it more strongly:

- Do not write complete paths into the `#include` statements ever.

If you do write them, it radically limits the portability of your code.  You can't rely on other people's machines having software installed in the same place as it is installed on your system.  If you tried it in open source software, you'd be laughed out of court.

Be wary of people who get cute with `../somedir/header.h` too — see [What are the benefits of a relative path such as "../include/header.h" for a header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597318/).

---

I observe that the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/) manual has an [example program](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/An-Example-Program.html#An-Example-Program) which starts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>
```

and the section on [Compiling and Linking](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Compiling-and-Linking.html#Compiling-and-Linking) says:

> The library header files are installed in their own `gsl` directory. You should write any preprocessor include statements with a `gsl/` directory prefix thus,
>
> ```
> #include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
> ```
>
> If the directory is not installed on the standard search path of your compiler you will also need to provide its location to the preprocessor as a command line flag. The default location of the `gsl` directory is `/usr/local/include/gsl`.

Answer (score 4):

In general it's a bad idea to write paths into the `#include` statements unless you really have to; it causes just this kind of problem.

On your lab computer, edit `R_wrapper.c`:

```
#include <gsl_randist.h>
#include <gsl_rng.h>
```

**The build should now fail.** If so then this verifies that you don't have other versions of these headers floating around, or links to them, or whatever. Confirm that it fails, then back out the change, and confirm that it works again.

Then add `-I/opt/local/include/gsl` to `CFLAGS`. **Verify that the makefile still works.**

Then edit `R_wrapper.c` again; now the build should succeed.

Decide where you would like to keep these files (`gsl_randist.h` and `gsl_rnd.h`) on your personal computer, and modify `CFLAGS` accordingly on your home version of the makefile.

Once all of that is working perfectly, we can show you how to write one makefile that will work on both machines.

Also, you can improve your makefile rules in other ways, but I must ask one question first:

```
G.o : G.c G.h constants.h utilities.h develop.h 
    $gcc $(CFLAGS) G.c develop.c
```

Does `G.o` really require `develop.c`? If so then you should probably reexamine your source files, because this is really unhygienic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Beta. So I changed `R_wrapper.c` on my lab computer. to get rid of the whole path in `#include <...>`. Compilation failed, indeed. Then I changed my make file to add `-I/opt/local/include/gsl` to `CFLAGS`. I don't know what you mean by `Verify that the makefile still works.` I tried to compile with my edited makefile on my lab computer and it failed. I then edited my makefile changing `-I/opt/local/include/gsl` to `-I/usr/local/include/gsl` because on my lab computer the gal folder is at `/usr/local/include/gsl`.

Comment: `-I/opt/local/include/gsl` is the location of the `gsl` folder on my computer. So I am stuck here in your procedure.

Comment: @Remi.b: I think you missed a step. **"Back out the change and confirm that it works again."** That is, revert to the original version of `R_wrapper.c` (containing the paths) and verify that the build system works again. *Then* try adding `-I/opt/local/include/gsl` to `CFLAGS`. Small steps.

Comment: Ok, I couldn't work on that for some time. I'm back now. By steps: 1) On `ComputerLab`, on `R_wrapper`, get rid of paths again. It fails to compile. 2) On `ComputerLab`, on `R_wrapper`, put the paths back. It compiles. 3) On `ComputerLab` add `-I/opt/local/include/gsl` to `CFLAGS`. It compiles 4) On `ComputerLab`, on `R_wrapper`, get rid of paths. It compiles.5) Decide where the `gsl` folder is on my computer. Decided! 6) Change the CFLAGS accordingly (on the `Makefile` on my computer). Done! 7) It DOES NOT COMPILE! Did I miss something? Thank you

Comment: Please have a look to the update in my question. That might help solving the issue or might help understand what I don't understand!