# How to include C++ header file which is not in the same directory as the current source file without using '..'?

Tags: c++

For example:

> project/utility/a.cpp

and

> project/utility/a.h

are implementation file and header file for a batch of functions that are used everywhere in this project.

Now, imagine

> project/component/b.h

would like to include `a.h`. A common solution is to use:

`#include "../utility/a.h"`

in `b.h`.

But this is not allowed in [Google C++ style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Names_and_Order_of_Includes):

> All of a project's header files should be listed as descendants of the project's source directory without use of UNIX directory shortcuts `.` (the current directory) or `..` (the parent directory).

I tried to include it as showed in the document above, but it does not work.

> **So what should I do to include it without using '.' or '..' ?**

Comment: You specify a path to the top include directory using the `-I` option of the compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See also [What are the benefits of a relative path such as "../include/header.h" for a header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597318/) and [Should I use `#include` in headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486)

You need to decide on whether to use just the base name of the header file (`a.h` in your question's abbreviated example), or whether to use a subdirectory plus header name `project/a.h`).  Either is workable as long as the header names are unique; the subdirectory version is often better and requires fewer command line options, in general.

You can write:

```
#ifndef B_H_INCLUDED
#define B_H_INCLUDED

#include "utility/a.h"

…other material required…

#endif /* B_H_INCLUDED */
```

and then, on the compiler command line, include an option:

```
-I ..
```

This ensures that the compiler will find `utility/a.h` as `../utility/a.h` (unless there's a name conflict somewhere).  Or you can specify the absolute path to your project:

```
-I /path/to/project
```

which will read `/path/to/project/utility/a.h`.

Answer (score 5):

> **So what should I do to include it without using '.' or '..' ?**

You specify a path to the top include directory using the `-I` option of the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should use Makefile or better to use automake.
Since you are using C++, your make file simply add the header path to the
CXXFLAGS variable.

----- your make file -----
Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS += -I../utility
VPATH = ../utility

yourprog : b.o 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ ../utility/a.o
```

In your source file, you only need to

```
#include "a.h"
```

In the Makefile, it is better to also add LDFLAGS. This segment of the Makefile is only showing the relevant part.  A complete Makefile has many more lines of code.  the -I compiler option tells the compiler to find herder files in the directory.  You can have multiple -I options for the compiler.  This is similar to the PATH variable in unix where your search path is separated by ":"