# How to use m5 in gem5-20 linking it with my own C++ program?

Tags: gem5

In gem5-20, I can build the m5 utility by using.

```
scons build/<arch>/out/m5
```

But actually I don’t know how to link M5 to my C++ code.

Some necessary operations are mentioned at the end of this document, but I hope to get more specific guidance.
http://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/m5ops/
Has anyone done it,please help me.
Thanks!
Best wishes!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On gem5 046645a4db646ec30cc36b0f5433114e8777dc44 I can do:

```
scons -C util/m5 build/x86/out/m5
gcc -static -I include -o main.out main.c util/m5/build/x86/out/libm5.a
```

with:

main.c

```
#include <gem5/m5ops.h>

int main(void) {
    m5_exit(0);
}
```

Or for ARM:

```
sudo apt install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-aarch64-linux-gnu
scons -C util/m5 build/aarch64/out/m5
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -static -I include -o main.out main.c \
  util/m5/build/aarch64/out/libm5.a
```

An official example can also be found at: [gem5-resources/src/simplem5_exit.c](https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5-resources/+/156e0bd1b5b2ca3377975b4bbedccb7e77efceea/src/simple/m5_exit.c) with instructions at [on the README](https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5-resources/+/156e0bd1b5b2ca3377975b4bbedccb7e77efceea/README.md#resource_simple).

And here is one using the `m5_exit_addr` variant, which uses the memory version of the m5op instead of instruction, which can also be used from KVM for example: https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/31219/7

But in practice, I often just don't have the patience for this business, so I just misbehave and add raw assembly directly [as shown here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/9be19ae1cf3f3f346a5bc25f4a4d1e1cbac23cb3/lkmc/m5ops.h) muahahaha e.g.:

```
#if defined(__x86_64__)

#define LKMC_M5OPS_CHECKPOINT __asm__ __volatile__ (".word 0x040F; .word 0x0043;" : : "D" (0), "S" (0) :)
#define LKMC_M5OPS_DUMPSTATS  __asm__ __volatile__ (".word 0x040F; .word 0x0041;" : : "D" (0), "S" (0) :)

#elif defined(__aarch64__)

#define LKMC_M5OPS_CHECKPOINT __asm__ __volatile__ ("mov x0, 0; mov x1, 0; .inst 0xFF000110 | (0x43 << 16);" : : : "x0", "x1")
#define LKMC_M5OPS_DUMPSTATS  __asm__ __volatile__ ("mov x0, 0; mov x1, 0; .inst 0xFF000110 | (0x41 << 16);" : : : "x0", "x1")
```

More general m5op information can also be found at: [What are pseudo-instructions for in gem5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63488050/what-are-pseudo-instructions-for-in-gem5/63489417#63489417)

Related:

- [How to use m5 in gem5-20 linking it with my own C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757008/how-to-use-m5-in-gem5-20/62759204#62759204)

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.