# Error: no such file or directory - C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

After interpreting this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281332/code-directory-structure-library-design#comment69813504_41281605),

```
/***************** arrayImpl.c **************/

#include"list/list.h"

#if defined(ARRAY)
 ....
#endif
```

I wrote `#include"list/list.h"` in `./Computing/list/arrayImpl.c` for testing `Computing/list` ADT using `Computing/testList.c` program, shown [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/blob/master/testList.c).

But `list/list.h` could not be found by `list/arrayImpl.c`, as shown below,

```
PC ~/code_practice/Computing
$ gcc -Wall -g -DARRAY ./list/*.c testList.c -o testList
./list/arrayImpl.c:3:22: fatal error: list/list.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
./list/linkedListImpl.c:3:22: fatal error: list/list.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

How do I understand this error, after following that comment? Did I mis-interpret?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I edited my query with `arrayImpl.c` code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.h` is in the same directory as the c files which include it. When you do

```
#include "list/list.h"
```

the compiler tries to find the file in include path + `/list`. For instance, it will look for `list/list/list.h` which doesn't exist.

So what would work would be changing to `#include "list.h"`

OR

add current directory to the command line using `-I.` so `list/list.h` is in include path.

```
gcc -Wall -g -I. -DARRAY ./list/*.c testList.c -o testList
```

From [gcc search path documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)

> -I. -I- is not the same as no -I options at all, and does not cause the same behavior for ‘<>’ includes that ‘""’ includes get with no special options. **-I. searches the compiler's current working directory for header files. That may or may not be the same as the directory containing the current file.**

It's not mentioned anywhere that include path contains the current directory, from which gcc was started.

Comment: I did many tests and the comment is wrong. Check my edit, the documentation doesn't talk about current directory.

Comment: When gcc doc says: *That may or may not be the same as the directory containing the current file.* It mean, the directory `list` containing with current file `arrayImpl.c` in this context. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, exactly. The current compiled file dir is automatically added to the compiler search path for this compilation only, unless file is included using `<>`, which tells to not include current compiled file dir.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add include file directory "list".

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html

> gcc -Wall -g -DARRAY ./list/*.c testList.c **-I list** -o testList

And you must remove "list" from "#include "list/list.h". Because when you write that you tell to the compiler to search in all include directory a file "list/list.h". But "list.h" is in "list". So "list" is not necessary.

```
#include "list.h"
```

---

You could do that but it's ugly

```
#include "../list/list.h"
```

Comment: `$ gcc -Wall -g -DARRAY ./list/*.c testList.c -I list  -o testList` gives same error

Comment: @overexchange fixed my bad