# How can I create a Makefile to compile my C code correctly?

Tags: c, makefile, webserver

The problem is that my webserver works fine when I compile my code in terminal using gcc directly:

```
gcc webserver.c ../include/webserverinit.c ../include/webserver_request_response.c -o webserver
```

but after using Makefile the code doesn't work fine. I don't get any error but one of the functions doesn't work correctly

I don't understand what is happening here. I know my code is ok and to make sure the Makefile is working fine, I used some Makefile generator as well but it is still the same.

I know my code is ok and to make sure the Makefile is working fine I used some Makefile generator as well but it is still the same

Makefile that I'm using:

```
CC=gcc
WEBSERVER_OBJECT=./objects/webserver.o
WEBSERVER_SOURCE=./src/webserver.c
WEBSERVERINIT_OBJECT=./objects/webserverinit.o #Library to start the webserver and listening on the port
WEBSERVERINIT_SOURCE=./include/webserverinit.c
WEBSERVERINIT_HEADER=./include/webserverinit.h
WEBSERVER_REQUEST_RESPONSE_OBJECT=./objects/webserver_request_response.o #Library for receiving requests and sending respons
WEBSERVER_REQUEST_RESPONSE_SOURCE=./include/webserver_request_response.c
WEBSERVER_REQUEST_RESPONSE_HEADER=./include/webserver_request_response.h
OBJECTS=./objects/webserver.o ./objects/webserverinit.o ./objects/webserver_request_response.o #objects folder
HEADERS=./include/webserverinit.h ./include/webserver_request_response.h #headers
OBJECTDIR=./objects

webserver: ${OBJECTS}
    ${CC} ${OBJECTS} -o webserver

${WEBSERVER_OBJECT}: ${WEBSERVER_SOURCE} ${HEADERS}
    ${CC} -c  ${WEBSERVER_SOURCE} -o ${WEBSERVER_OBJECT}

${WEBSERVERINIT_OBJECT}: ${WEBSERVERINIT_SOURCE} ${WEBSERVERINIT_HEADER}
    ${CC} -c ${WEBSERVERINIT_SOURCE} -o ${WEBSERVERINIT_OBJECT}   

${WEBSERVER_REQUEST_RESPONSE_OBJECT}: ${WEBSERVER_REQUEST_RESPONSE_SOURCE} ${WEBSERVER_REQUEST_RESPONSE_HEADER}
    ${CC} -c ${WEBSERVER_REQUEST_RESPONSE_SOURCE} -o ${WEBSERVER_REQUEST_RESPONSE_OBJECT} 
clean:
    rm -rf ${OBJECTDIR}/*.o webserver
```

I want my code works with Makefile as well but it is not working with Makefile. What should I do?

Comment: Compare the compiler commands make emits with the ones you are using manually. What is the difference?

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks for your advice....I compared my Makefile with manual command but I couldn't find any difference... I know the problem should be with my Makefile but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create a Makefile to compile my C code correctly?

You need a [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (e.g. [`emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) which knows the peculiarities of [`Makefile`s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) in particular the weird role of <kbd>tab</kbd> characters in them.

> `CFLAGS=-c -o`

That is probably wrong. You might want `CFLAGS= -g -Wall` instead. Hint: run `make -p` to understand the builtin rules of `make` and take advantage of them.

> `WEBSERVERINIT_SOURCE=./include/webserverinit.c`

And that looks strange (I guess that you should replace `include` with `src`).

---

First, you need to **read documentation**. In particular, about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) on the command line, and later read the [GNU `make` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html). **Spend several hours to read** each of them.

Then, you might want to use the `-v` and `-H` flags to `gcc`. Both are helpful.

At last, you should use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) : it is an improved variant of `make` (designed to ease debugging of your `Makefile`). You'll use it with the `-x` flag.

Comment: @amireghbalian: from my perspective, what's odd about `./include/webserverinit.c` is that you don't normally put source files such as `webserverinit.c` in a directory `include` which sounds like it will contain headers.  I can't be sure that's what Basile was thinking of.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes...you are right.... source files should be in source directory instead of include directory but I don't think it solves the problem

Comment: @amireghbalian: When `webserver.c` includes `webserverinit.h`, what do you write as the `#include` line?  `#include "webserverinit.h"`?  Something else?  You might need `-I./include` on the compiler command lines — possibly as part of `CFLAGS`.   Your `CFLAGS` should include options such as `-O3 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror`.  The `-c` and `-o` options would normally be written verbatim in the command line; they don't vary between compilers.  I use separate names such as `WFLAG1 = -Wall` — `WFLAG2 = -Wextra` — `WFLAG3 = -Werror` — `WFLAGS = ${WFLAG1} ${WFLAG2} ${WFLAG3}` _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ and then `CFLAGS = … ${WFLAGS} …`.  That way, I can turn any of the warnings on or off from the command line: `make WFLAG3=` disables `-Werror`, for example.  I don't often use that unless I'm working on someone else's code that doesn't meet my coding standards.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler webserver.c is the main file and first, it uses webserverinit header (#include "../include/webserverinit.h"). it has 3 functions and all of them works fine.
another header is webserver_request_response which is responsible for getting a request from clients and sending a response to client. the function for getting request is working fine but the function for sending a response to the client doesn't work ok.

Comment: @amireghbalian: the working or not of the function in `webserver_request_response.c` is not related to the `makefile`; it is related to the code in the source file, and/or the headers it uses. At most, the differences in the build process mean a bug (with 'undefined behaviour') manifests itself differently.  If you create the executable, it probably isn't the `makefile` that's at fault. Note the question [What are the benefits of a relative path such as `"../include/header.h"` for a header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597318/)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'll check it out and test it...thanks

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you so much...You were right... the problem is related to the path...I put all the files in a single directory and used the Makefile and now it works fine