# Multiple source and header files: including .c and .h files

Tags: c

I have the following project structure:

```
/source:
-- data_module_entry.c (main.c)
-- /data_module
-- -- data_process.c
-- -- data_process.h
-- /data_libs
-- -- data_stat.c
-- -- data_stat.h
-- -- data_io.c
-- -- data_io.h
```

I have functions from `data_io.c` and from `data_process.c` in `data_module_entry.c`.

Also `data_process.c` uses functions from `data_stat.c`.

But I can't properly set up a links between those files to make it work.

What should be the exact sequences of `#include ""`?

Comment: `#include "../data_libs/data_io.h"` if including from a source file in one of your subdirectories.  If including from the "main" file / root directory, then simply `#include "data_libs/data_io.h"` _etc_...

Comment: I disagree with the suggestion to use relative paths (see also [What are the benefits of a relative path such as `"../include/header"` for a header?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/597318/15168)).  In this context, I think you should write `#include "data_module/data_process.h"` and `#include "data_libs/data_io.h"` (and `#include "data_libs/data_stat.h"`) in the source files (and in any headers that include other headers), and ensure that you specify `-I/source` or equivalent on the compiler command line.

Comment: "But I can't properly set up a links between those files to make it work." okay but... what problem do you see? What is your current include-sequence? How does the .h-files look?

Comment: Assuming that your .h files are written correctly (which we can't know), it's very simple. If X.c needs to call a function from Y.c then X.c must include Y.h. No magic...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did it all fine, it wasn't really a problem. However, when I used `gcc` I specified only the file with `main.c` instead of enumerating all of the `.c` files.