# c++ alternative for getch() and clrscr()

Tags: c++, getch

I use `code::blocks` 10.05 for compiling C++.

But I cannot use

```
getch()
```

It says `unknown`. When I `#include <conio>` it says unknown library. So what is the alternative to be able to use `getch` in C++?

Comment: what operating system are you on?

Comment: [Alternative function in iostream.h for getch() of conio.h?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1377403/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `#include <conio.h>`

Works fine on my machine (Windows and Linux, mingw compiler for Windows). As I know Code::Blocks uses gcc compiler.

Comment: thanks.it works.

But why does conio alone requires the context 'conio.h' where iostream can be declared simply

Comment: I am not sure, but think because iostream is C++ library and conio.h is from C

Comment: Rather than the extension being implicit to `#include`, the C++ standard library headers actually have no extension. Most other libraries (all that I'm aware of actually) use an extension such as `.h` or `.hpp`. As `#include` takes a full filename, if there is an extension you must add it.

Answer (score 1):

Header files with .h extension are **different** from those without h extension , you may refer this 
[C++ includes with and without .h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799682/c-includes-with-and-without-h)