# Printing all the ASCII Values in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

Hello Everyone its been Long that I am not in touch with the C/C++ Language and was just revising the concepts again and I came across this question which asked to write a program to display all the ASCII characters and I wrote the following good, but it is not giving expected result. Can anyone please tell what is the Problem with this code.

```
#include<iostrem.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char a;
    for(a = 0; a < 256; ++a)
    {
        cout << a << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no C/C++ language.

Comment: it may seem like a simple question but this shows some things, especially in regards to the max value of an unsigned char. use int instead or just char.

Comment: `<iostrem.h>` is not an standard library, maybe you wanted `<iostream>`

Comment: ASCII only contains 128 characters, so changing the `256` to `128` would produce the correct results.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`a` is *always* less than 256, since an unsigned char cannot possibly go higher than 255. You've written an infinite loop.

Your include also has a mispelling and extra `.h` and you didn't use the `std` namespace on `cout`.

edit: Finally, technically, ASCII only counts the first 128 characters, everything beyond that is the domain of various extended character sets.

Comment: Apologies for the Spelling mistake. But how come the loop is infinite...? as unsigned char has the range from 0 to 255 wouldn't the loop will terminate once it reaches 255...?

Comment: An unsigned char is only one byte long, so it has a maximum value of 255. When you add one to it, the one gets carried over and the first byte resets to zero. Imagine for example if you only had a two digit number. You can easily show 10-99. But if you did 99+1, you now get 100. What the computer does here though is just keep the last two digits - 00 - so it rolls back to where it started. Bytes work similarly, except the "digits" range from 0-255 and roll back over at 255+1.

Comment: its an unsigned char, cant go higher than 255

Comment: @RohitSaluja 255 < 256

Comment: "unsigned char cannot possibly go higher than 255."  - that usually is true.

Answer (score 6):

If you can use `<stdio.h>`, then it is easier.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
      fprintf(stdout, "[%d]: %c\n", i, i);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I love how C's `stdio` is so much easier to use (generally) than C++'s `iostream`, easier to internationalize too. The C++ folks really dropped the ball there!

Comment: I absolutely agree. I prefer `stdio` for things like this.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe you can still use [std::printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) in C++

Answer (score 5):

The other answers have this well covered. I just thought I would throw in that it might be good to check if the characters are printable before printing them:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for(int a = 0; a < 256; ++a) // use int (big enough for 256)
        if(std::isprint(a)) // check if printable
            std::cout << char(a) << " "; // print it as a char
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

=>C++

```
#include<iostream>
int main ()
{
    int a;
    for(a=0;a<256;++a)
    {
        cout<<(char)a<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

=>C

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int a;
    for(a=0;a<256;++a)
    {
        printf("%c " a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: upvote for showing solution in both languages, obviously #includes necessary though ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your code.

First there is no `iostrem.h`. After correcting this to `iostream.h` g++ will give a `fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory` because the [standard libraries must not be included with `.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/301586/995714)

Changing it to `#include <iostream>` results in the `error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope`. You need `std::cout << a` to make it compile successfully.

But even after resolving all the above problems, an important thing was output by gcc with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` option

```
warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
```

That's because 256 is outside `unsigned char`'s typical range. It only works if char has more than 8 bits, which is not the case of your platform. You should always enable all compiler warnings. That'll help you identify a lot of problems without the need to ask here.

Nevertheless, don't use types less than `int` for temporary values unless very necessary because they all will be promoted to `int` in expressions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

it works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a;
    int i;

    for (int i=0; i<256; i++){
        a=i;
        cout << i << " " << a << " " <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a very old question, but if anyone wanted to actually print the ASCII code along with its corresponding numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{  

char a; 

for (int a=0; a<=127; a++)
{
    std::cout<<a<<" ";
    std::cout<<int(a)<<" "<<std::endl;
}

return 0;

}
```

NB/to the reader:

code 0-31: unprintable chars; used for formatting & control printers

code 32-127: printable chars; represents letters, numbers & punctuation.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    unsigned char a;
    for(a=0;a<=255;a++)
    {
        printf(" %c  %d  \n ",a,a);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that'll print only characters from 0 to 254

Comment: That's still not working because after 255 a++ will overflow and become 0. The program will loop infinitely

Answer (score -1):

What result are you getting? I think you need to output

```
Cout<<(chat)a;
```

Otherwise it would only return the integer number that it assigned

Comment: i think you mean (char) but that is not his problem

Comment: On mobile..a lot typo